# Getting a java class object created in a testng class in testng listener

Tags: java, testng, listener

I have a java class called DataReadHelper and i am creating a object of the mentioned class in my testng class

```
import DataReadHelper

public class testclass{

@BeforeSuite
public void initiate{
    DataReadHelper dataread = new DataReadHelper("D:\\Test.xlsx");
}
```

Now i have a testng listener class which is implementing iTestResult listener and i want to verify whether the object for this class is created or not in the testng listener class

I have already tried many things but with no success, How can i achieve it? Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu can use `ITestContext` in order to store the object:

1. Pass it as a parameter of `@BeforeSuite` method and save your object into it: `context.setAttribute("dataread", dataread)`
2. Restore the object from the listener: `DataReadHelper dataread = result.getTestContext().getAttribute("dataread")`